# Checking if the file is rar through its bytes

Tags: c#, security, byte

I am trying to verify that the file is a .rar file through its bytes for security purposes. Th following code is my code the only problem is that the sub-header is not matching with the one generated from the file. I noticed that is different for different file. Could you please explain to me why?

```
 static bool IsRARFile(string filePath)
    {
        bool isDocFile = false;
        //
        // File sigs from: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html
        //
        string msOfficeHeader = "52-61-72-21-1A-07-00-CF";
        string docSubHeader = "64-2E-63-73";

        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            //get file header
            byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[8];
            stream.Read(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
            string headerString = BitConverter.ToString(headerBuffer);

            if (headerString.Equals(msOfficeHeader, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                //get subheader
                byte[] subHeaderBuffer = new byte[4];
                stream.Seek(512, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.Read(subHeaderBuffer, 0, subHeaderBuffer.Length);
                string subHeaderString = BitConverter.ToString(subHeaderBuffer);

                if (subHeaderString.Equals(docSubHeader, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    isDocFile = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isDocFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have just copied a function from somewhere for a different filetype and not every filetype has any notion of a "subheader". You only need to check the main header in the case of RAR.

I also suggest modifying the naming of the variables, it is quite a mismash if a function says it's checking for RAR type and internally all variables refer to DOCs.

Comment: yes I did :D I am guilty! ok thats why... It worked for the zip file :D thanks!